# 2000 Toyota Camry power seat will not move forward more than 1" from back position.

Tags: toyota, seat

2000 Toyota Camry power seat will not move forward more than 1" from the far back position.  When I move the switch to move it forward the seat will move about 1" and stop and it will also move that far to the back. It behaves like it come to the end of the track. I have checked and there are no visible obstructions or damage. Based on the fact that it moves 1" forward and backwards I believe I can rule out the motor and switch.

Comment: Take the seat up from the floor of the vehicle ... should only be four fasteners. Check the mechanicals to ensure nothing is broke or askew.

Answer (score 1):

Give direct power supply to motor by disconnecting the motor plug connection and see what happens. If motor is working fine, you should notice movement of seats more than 1". If motor is working fine, then check the input to motor by using multimeter in voltage mode. Don't forget to actuate the switch

Answer (score 0):

I have seen coins get dropped into the tracks and it will stop it cold, just like it has hit a stop at the end of travel. As the comment above says, remove the seat and look in the tracks for a coin. It is possible to see and get them out without removing the seat, sometimes, with something sticky on a screwdriver, or compressed air to blow it out. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

after checking the motor if it works.the issue can only be jammed seat tracks or jammed seat gearbox which a little lubrication should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dropped coins on the floor and one of them got caught in the track. Or maybe it's some other foreign object. There should be 4 bolts holding your seat in place. Remove the bolts, disconnect the connection switches underneath the seat and place the seat on top of the rear seats. I've never tried what I'm about to tell you now but I myself would consider linking the seat switch with the connector on the seat floor by using 2 long wires. one for the positive side of the switch and one for the negative side-- so that you might be able to get power to your track for testing purposes while the seat is NOT in it's position. perhaps you'll be able to see the movement and locate, and remedy the blockage much easier without the seat in the way.